# Android 4.0 Error

Tags: android

Is there any fault in the following code:

```
public void onclick2(View v)
    {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "LOADING", "PLEASE WAIT",true);
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
}
```

The following error is come:

```
The device not found
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code. You might have to restart your adb.

Comment: I want to display the progress bar for 5 seconds and didmiss

Comment: good for you. still the issue is not related to your code

Answer (score 0):

From your console try `adb start-server`.
If you have USB debbuging on your device enabled, you should see it when you run `adb devices`.